# How to connect to local outlook via IMAP or POP3

Tags: outlook, imap, local, pop3

my company denies any remote connections to our local working environment, and I need to connect to outlook application using IMAP or Pop3 for automation purposes (internal connection).
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is this a programming question or are you asking how to configure Outlook, the windows program?

Comment: Configuration is beyond the scope of stackoverflow.  But generally, you get your admins to open the IMAP port on the local instance of Exchange, and give you the hostname, and enable the accounts for IMAP access.  But, maybe you should be considering Outlook Scripting?